# i have a process that is blocked.but one thread of this process is (not running) still executing something

Tags: multithreading, process, block

how does the threads library affect this activity?is the threads library responsible for this?if it is,is the threads library the only responsible?
and if you can,explain me what is exactly the threads library....

Comment: thread library? what is it? which platform do you speak about? language? consider making your question clearer to receive better answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A process can often appear "blocked" if it's user interface thread is waiting on a routine.  This may be the only thread in the program, but that thread is doing something computationally intensive, and prevents the user interface from updating.

That is really a separate issue from threading libraries, however.

Comment: so,there is no connection between what ,you and i,said, and the threading libraries?

Comment: No, not necessarily.  A process can appear "blocked" and still only have one thread (ie: not using a "threading library"), but still use 100% CPU.